# Unknown characters

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

I read the string from file with encoding "UTF-8". And I need to match it to a expression.
The first character of the file is `#`, but in the string the first is `''`(empty symbol). I have translated it into bytes with charset "UTF-8", here it is `[-17, -69, -65]`. Does anyone know what is it and how to solve it with regexprs?

Comment: Can paste [hexdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) of start of file? That is, the raw data before Java even touches it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some editors (like notepad) adds BOM (byte order mask) signature when saved UTF-8 text. You should check 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF bytes before read string from such file and skip them if they exists.

Another way is do not use notepad for editing UTF-8 texts, get other program like Notepad++, Kate or whatever with witch you can control adding BOM.