# Why an actual number string read from a text can't be parsed with method Integer.valueOf() in java?

Tags: java, parsing

Why an actual number string read from a text can't be parsed with method `Integer.valueOf()` in java?

**Exception** :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11127"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at sharingBike.ReadTxt.readRecord(ReadTxt.java:91)
    at sharingBike.ReadTxt.main(ReadTxt.java:17)
```

This is my code

```
        File fileView = new File(filePath);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileView), "UTF-8"));

        String line;

        int count = 0;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] lins = line.split(";");

            int value;
            value = Integer.valueOf(lins[0]);}
```

Comment: `valueOf` returns an object of type `Integer`, not a primitive. Use `parseInt` instead.

Comment: your code should work, the only option i can imagine is that you have trailing spaces in that string/integer value that you are trying to parse...

Comment: @ØyvindHauge: `public static int parseInt(String s)` ?

Comment: I assume some non-printable bytes inside the string. Please output them as `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lins[0].getBytes(UTF_8)))` just to see what you have here. See @assylias answer for a possible example.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I used the exact string posted in the question (but the BOM bit got lost with the edit of @AndrewTobilko).

Comment: @assylias Weird. I now also see the BOM (copy-paste into NP++ with hex editor). Very good finding!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Tried to rollback but apparently it's not possible to keep the original string and have the exception formatted...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the content of your string:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("11127".getBytes()));
```

which outputs:

> [-17, -69, -65, 49, 49, 49, 50, 55]

The first three bytes are [a UTF-8 BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494570/unknown-characters).

You can fix it by removing non-digits from the string first (and use `parseInt` to return an `int` instead of an `Integer`):

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(lins[0].replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Comment: thumbs up for the UTF-BOM

Comment: I really don't expect that so strange this problem is in my eye, but can still have exactly right answer to sovle it so quickly! StackOverFlow is powerful,I know it right now. HAHA